# Why route root did not work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am following the tutorial Ruby on Rails Tutorials by Michael Hartl and try to finish the last step in section 3.4.4. When I change routes.rb to

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
 root 'static_pages#home'
 get  'static_pages/help'
 get  'static_pages/about'
end
```

and relaunch http://localhost:3000/static_pages , they said "We're sorry, but something went wrong". Then I relaunch http://localhost:3000/static_pages/help and it works. Then I check the routes by

```
rake routes
```

And the result shows:

```
Prefix Verb URI Pattern                   Controller#Action
          root GET  /                             static_pages#home
static_pages_help GET  /static_pages/help(.:format)  static_pages#help
static_pages_about GET  /static_pages/about(.:format) static_pages#about
```

I check the content in file static_pages_controller.rb and no difference as that in tutorial. Could someone tell me what is wrong?

Comment: Aren't you backwards? Doesn't your route definition mean if you access `http://localhost:3000/` it will invoke the action `home` on controller `static_pages`? What URL are you trying to map (and to what controller/action)?

Comment: Solved the issue. Forgive me I am new in web development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, with this route mapping `root 'static_pages#home'`, you said, when you hit `http://localhost:3000/` url, you will be mapped to the `home` action of the `StaticPages` controller.

But you didn't define any mapping for `http://localhost:3000/static_pages`, it is incorrect url as per the `route.rb` file. That's why you got the error.

Read the first line of the output of `rake routes`, it is clearly telling what you have defined.

Answer (score 0):

The line `root 'static_pages#home'` is equivalent to `get '/', to: 'static_pages#home'`. This means that the URL `localhost:3000/` is being routed to the `#home` action on the StaticPages controller.

If you want `localhost:3000/static_pages` to point to the `#home` action, add this line:

`get 'static_pages', to: 'static_pages#home'`